# Why friction is not considered in thermodynamic cycles?

Tags: thermodynamics, gas, viscosity

Why viscosity is not considered in thermodynamic cycles and what is the impact of viscosity in the first of law thermodynamics? The gases have high viscosity and there exist a pressure drop, I haven't seen it in my thermodynamic books, but I think this must be important in engineering.

Comment: See Bird et al, Transport phenomena, Chapter 11, Problem 11.D.1

Answer (score 1):

> Why friction is not considered in thermodynamic cycles?

Friction is not considered in *reversible* thermodynamic cycles because to be reversible, there can be no friction. Friction is considered for *irreversible* thermodynamic cycles. The first law, which is essentially the law of conservation of energy, applies to both reversible and irreversible cycles.

The difference between a reversible and irreversible cycle is entropy is generated in the irreversible cycle, such as by viscous friction, and not in the reversible cycle where there can be no friction. In general, that means less work is done in the irreversible cycle since the entropy generated in the system (by friction or other means) needs to be transferred to the surroundings in the form of heat in order to complete the cycle. That leaves less of the heat transferred to the system available to perform work.

Hope this helps.